# Image hover zoom in effect to be applied for all images

Tags: css, image

Could you please help me how can i apply Image hover zoom in effect to be applied on all images at once on particular page? Do I have to use some ID or CLASS to name the images?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on my own :) .. you have to:

1. name the class, f.e. class="item" and to embed it between a and href within HTML of a linked image
2. use a simple CSS with opacity f.e.

.item img {
opacity:1;
transition:. .1s ease-in-out;
}

.item img:hover {
opacity:0.87;
cursor:pointer;
}